# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on boolean

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm writing a simple database to practice, but I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on boolean in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php on line 43

The query line is line 43, but I can't figure why it's a boolean as neither `$conn` or `$db_handle` is `false`, why is this?

```
    <?php

    $server = "localhost";
    $database = "motocross_db";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    $conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password);
    $db_handle = $conn->select_db($database);

    if ($db_handle)
    {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
        {
            // upload
        }

        $enrollments_sql = "SELECT
                               users.first_name,
                               users.last_name,
                               registrations.attendance_date,
                               registrations.attendance_location,
                               bikes.bike_brand,
                               bikes.engine_size,
                               bikes.bike_type
                        FROM users
                        INNER JOIN registrations
                           ON users.user_id = registrations.user_id
                        INNER JOIN bikes
                           ON registrations.bike_id = bikes.bike_id";

        $enrollments_result = $db_handle->query($enrollments_sql);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
$db_handle->query($enrollments_sql);
```

To

```
$conn->query($enrollments_sql);// use $conn here
```

Because `mysqli_query()` need first parameter as your database connection

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php